# Interconnect modules in for loop with different connectivity on some ports between different instances

Tags: verilog

Is it possible to instantiate a module in a `for` loop and change some port connectivity between different instances using an `if` statement?

Something like:

```
genvar g_i;
generate
        for (g_i = 0; g_i < PWLINK_NUM; g_i++) begin : pwrlink

    pdndlvrlnlpwrlinkvert_cbb pdndlvrlnlpwrlink_cbb(
    if (g_i == 0) begin
      .dftmeasen(pwr_dftmeasen),      
    end
    else begin
      .dftmeasen(1'b0),       
    end
      .bldr_en(bldr_en[g_i]), 
      .bldr_mode(bldr_mode[g_i]), 
      .bldr_strength(bldr_strength[g_i]), 
      .hven(hvenout[g_i]), 
      .legacy_mode_en(legacy_mode_en[g_i]), 
      .force_on(force_on[g_i]), 
      .pwrup(pwrup[g_i]),

 end
endgenerate
```

Answer (score 0):

I get a compile error when I try to use `if-else` inside a `generate` `for` loop that way.

One way to do this is to declare a new signal and connect it to the instance port just like all the other ports:

```
wire [PWLINK_NUM-1:0] dftmeasen = { {(PWLINK_NUM-1){1'b0}}, pwr_dftmeasen};

genvar g_i;
generate

for (g_i = 0; g_i < PWLINK_NUM; g_i++) begin : pwrlink

    pdndlvrlnlpwrlinkvert_cbb pdndlvrlnlpwrlink_cbb (
        .dftmeasen (dftmeasen[g_i]),      
        .bldr_en   (bldr_en  [g_i]),
```

Answer (score 0):

One possibilty is to define a temp signal for *dftmeasen* differently for differnt iterations, like int the following. *tmp* is defined as a *wire* for iteration  0 and as a *parameter* for the rest. The only secret is to have named blocks in the *if* statement with the same name in both paths. I used *i* for the name.

```
 for (genvar g_i = 0; g_i < PWLINK_NUM; g_i++) begin : pwrlink
    if (g_i == 0) begin: i // << 
        wire tmp = pwr_dftmeasen;
    end: i
    else begin: i // <<
        parameter bit tmp = 0;
    end: i

    pdndlvrlnlpwrlinkvert_cbb pdndlvrlnlpwrlink_cbb(
      .dftmeasen(i.tmp),      // i.tmp
      .bldr_en(bldr_en[g_i])
    );
  end
```